# Is there a term for a set of functions which is unchanged under permutations of its variables?

Tags: terminology

A [symmetric *function*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricFunction.html) is a function which is unchanged under any permutation of its variables, for example:

$$f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz$$

There are *sets* of functions in which the individual functions are not symmetric but the set as a whole is unchanged under any permutation of the variables in the functions.  An example is the set comprising the following three functions:

$$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + yz$$
$$g(x,y,z) = y^2 + xz$$
$$h(x,y,z) = z^2 + xy$$

Is there a term for such a set of functions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a standard term for that property, but *invariant set* seems clear enough.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1231983)

Comment: @Klangen From my perspective as the OP it is quite helpful to know that a high-rep user thinks there is no standard term for the property.  It reassures me that my failure to find such a term from my own searching was not just because I was looking in the wrong places.